# Iframe on mozilla popup issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mozilla

I have a problem with popups when I call iframe.

Here is a picture:

[image: Picture of Mozilla popup]

I don't want to get this popup.

This is my script:

```
function readfile() { 
alert(document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

This is the call from text link:

```
<li><a href="e90_data/sasija/prazno.txt" style="text-decoration: none" target="iframe_a">Prazno</a></li>
```

This is the iframe on the end of the page:

```
<iframe id='iframe' name="iframe_a" src = 'demo_iframe.htm' est.align="top" width=900px height=550px > <p>Vas browser ne podrzava IFRAME!.</p> </iframe>
```

On Chrome it appears normally, without a popup.

Comment: this is how mozilla firefox outputs the alert popup window. if you want to avoid this popup you will need to look into something called as modal windows

Comment: try `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument` for ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting)

> From the DOM iframe element, scripts can get access to the window object of the included HTML page via the contentWindow property. The contentDocument property refers to the document  element inside the iframe (this is equivalent to contentWindow.document), but is not supported by Internet Explorer versions before IE8.

I think you want to be using contentWindow.